# How to call a variable in multiple screens

Tags: python, variables, kivy

Basically I have a variable called `cart` in my .py file and I would like to call it in multiple screens in my .kv file. Currently I only have it in the `FirstScreen` class. Would there be a way to call the `cart` variable in `FirstScreen` and `SecondScreen`?

I've tried putting the `cart = NumericProperty(0)` line in the `MyApp` class and change the Label from `str(root.cart)` to `str(app.cart)` but it gives me this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty' and 'int'`. I made a simple example to show what I want to achieve.

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def Lasagna(self,button):
        self.cart += 7
        print(self.cart)

    def sizeSelection1(self):
        sizepopup = FloatLayout()
        sizepop = Popup(title="Format", separator_color=[0.6, 0, 0, 1], content=sizepopup, size_hint=(0.6, 0.6))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Label(text="Choose a format", pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.4}))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Small", size_hint=(1, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.6}, on_release = self.Lasagna ))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Back", size_hint=(0.8, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0.10, "y": 0}, on_release=sizepop.dismiss))
        sizepop.open()

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def Patato(self,button):
        self.cart += 3
        print(self.cart)


    def sizeSelection2(self):
        sizepopup = FloatLayout()
        sizepop = Popup(title="Format", separator_color=[0.6, 0, 0, 1], content=sizepopup, size_hint=(0.6, 0.6))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Label(text="Choose a format", pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.4}))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Small", size_hint=(1, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.6}, on_release = self.Patato))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Back", size_hint=(0.8, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0.10, "y": 0}, on_release=sizepop.dismiss))
        sizepop.open()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class exampleApp(App):
    #cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exampleApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<WindowManager>:
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: "first"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "FirstScreen"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.3,"y":0.3}
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.5}
            on_release:
                root.sizeSelection1()
        Label:
            text: str(root.cart) + "$"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5,"y":0.7}
        Button:
            text: "Second screen"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.3}
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "left")
                app.root.current = "second"

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "second"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "SecondScreen"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.3,"y":0.3}
        Label:
            text: str(root.cart) + "$"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5,"y":0.7}
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.5}
            on_release:
                root.sizeSelection2()
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.3}
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "right")
                app.root.current = "first"
```

Comment: I found some useful information in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244978/python-kv-file-how-to-call-function-from-another-class try them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the value `cart` inside your running app. To do this you can get the current running app. And then acces this value in each screen using app instead of root.

#### py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def Lasagna(self,button):
        App.get_running_app().cart += 7

    def sizeSelection1(self):
        sizepopup = FloatLayout()
        sizepop = Popup(title="Format", separator_color=[0.6, 0, 0, 1], content=sizepopup, size_hint=(0.6, 0.6))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Label(text="Choose a format", pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.4}))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Small", size_hint=(1, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.6}, on_release = self.Lasagna ))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Back", size_hint=(0.8, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0.10, "y": 0}, on_release=sizepop.dismiss))
        sizepop.open()


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def Patato(self,button):
        App.get_running_app().cart += 3

    def sizeSelection2(self):
        sizepopup = FloatLayout()
        sizepop = Popup(title="Format", separator_color=[0.6, 0, 0, 1], content=sizepopup, size_hint=(0.6, 0.6))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Label(text="Choose a format", pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.4}))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Small", size_hint=(1, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.6}, on_release = self.Patato))
        sizepopup.add_widget(Button(text="Back", size_hint=(0.8, 0.15), pos_hint={"x": 0.10, "y": 0}, on_release=sizepop.dismiss))
        sizepop.open()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class exampleApp(App):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exampleApp().run()
```

#### kv

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<WindowManager>:
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: "first"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "FirstScreen"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.3,"y":0.3}
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.5}
            on_release:
                root.sizeSelection1()
        Label:
            text: str(app.cart) + "$"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5,"y":0.7}
        Button:
            text: "Second screen"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.3}
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "left")
                app.root.current = "second"

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "second"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "SecondScreen"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.3,"y":0.3}
        Label:
            text: str(app.cart) + "$"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5,"y":0.7}
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.5}
            on_release:
                root.sizeSelection2()
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25,"y":0.3}
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "right")
                app.root.current = "first"
```

If you really want to use root you have to change the cart value to be in the WindowManager class instead.